# How to center elements and avoid them being cut off the screen with a horizontal scrollable div with justifyContent: "center"?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, scroll, overflow, centering

I can't find a way to center my horizontal scrollable div without using justifyContent:"center". Thing is, when justifyContent:"center" is being used, and the scroll indicator bar is shown it also cut off part of the elements that are being rendered inside the div.

I've already tried using alignContent, alignItems, alignSelf with different results. But none of them works as expected.

```
<div
  style={{
   display: 'flex',
   overflowX: 'scroll',
   justifyContent: 'center',                    
  }}
>
 {data.map(() => {
   return (
    <View>
      <cmp />
    </View>
   );
  })}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using justify-content: center, you can achieve the desired effect by using width: fit-content in combination with margin: auto.

Instead of:

```html
<div
  style={{
   display: 'flex',
   overflowX: 'scroll',
   justifyContent: 'center',                    
  }}
>
```

You can use:

```html
<div
  style={{
   display: 'flex',
   overflowX: 'scroll',
   justifyContent: 'flex-start',
   width: 'fit-content',
   margin: 'auto',
  }}
>
```